# group containing normal subgroups of orders $3$ and $5$ contains element of order $15$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I want to prove that 'Let $G$ be a group containing normal subgroups of orders $3$ and $5$, respectively. Prove $G$ contains 
>   an element of order $15$'.
>
> How can I use this fact for proof: 'Let $r$ and $s$ be relatively prime integers. A cyclic group of order $rs$ is isomorphic to the product of a cyclic group of order $r$ and a cyclic group of order $s$.' ?

I first thought that I get the proof obviously, but then I saw 'normal' in question, and stopped.

Also, the cyclic subgroup generated by that order $15$ element has to be normal in $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a roadmap:

- Prove that $H_3 H_5 = H_5 H_3$
- Prove that $H_3 H_5$ is a normal subgroup
- Prove that $H_3 H_5 \cong H_3 \times H_5 \cong C_3 \times C_5 \cong C_{15}$

Comment: What happens when normality is taken away? We need normality in proof of $H_3 H_5 = H_5 H_3$?

Comment: The result is no longer true. For example $S_5$ has elements of order $3$ and $5$ but no element of order $15$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. When normality assumed, can $C_{15}$ be non-normal in $G$? Also we need normality in $H_3 H_5 = H_5 H_3$, right?

Comment: Yes, if $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of any group $G$, then so is $MN = NM$. (Since you have accepted the answer, you must understand everything already!)

Comment: @DerekHolt Do we really need HK to be normal in G , is it not enough for HK to be just a subgroup of G ? and since H and K has order 3 and 5 they contain an element of order 3 and 5 , x , y , resp, so the order of that element xy is 15.